# Should we divide div vertically with line and without table structure?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Asp.net MVC. I am making my project on the student management system. In this project, I need to display the final results of the student with the divided form. So I am in trouble with displaying results.

**My actual result is like this image:**

[image: Wanted Result]

I am trying below code:

```
<div>25<hr>30</div>
```

I'll get this result:

[image: Now Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `style="display: inline-block;"` to the div and it will work.

Comment: If anything to replace <hr> tag.

Comment: Use style="clear:both;" this will replace your <hr> tag, and use border-bottom for line.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.result {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.result li:first-child {
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    width: fit-content;
    line-height: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="result"><li>25</li><li>30</li></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The final answer is

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;">
25 
<div style="clear:both;border-bottom:1px solid;"></div> 
30
</div>
```